# SensorGesture from qml plugin not working

Tags: ios, qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I am following [this tutorial](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtsensors-sensorgesture.html) to detect shaking of the phone. This is a part of iOS app development.

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import QtMultimedia 5.0
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0
import QtSensors 5.0 as Sensors

SceneBase {
    id: screen

///*** Code of Interest ***///

    Sensors.SensorGesture {
        id: sensorGesture
        enabled: true
        gestures : ["QtSensors.shake"]

        onDetected: {
          console.log("phone shake detected")
        }
    }

/// ************************* ///

    Sensors.Gyroscope {
        id: gyro
        dataRate: 10
        active: true

        onReadingChanged: {
            if (reading.y > 1100){
                console.log("rapid motion detected")
            }
        }
    }

    //... bunch of other code
}
```

All other `Sensors` work fine when code pertaining to `Sensors.SensorGesture` is commented out. However, it gives the following error when the code is uncommented.

```
Could not load  QtQuick2Plugin(0x146a5b80)
Could not load  QtQuick2WindowPlugin(0x146a7df0)
Could not load  QMultimediaDeclarativeModule(0x146a4020)
Could not load  QtQuickLayoutsPlugin(0x146a8120)
Could not load  QtSensorsDeclarativeModule(0x146aa6d0)
Could not load  QtQuickControlsPlugin(0x146aa870)
Could not load  QQmlLocalStoragePlugin(0x146aa9c0)
Could not load  QtQuick2ParticlesPlugin(0x146aa9e0)
Could not load  AVFServicePlugin(0x146aabf0)
Could not load  AVFMediaPlayerServicePlugin(0x146aac20)
Could not load  AudioCaptureServicePlugin(0x145a83e0)
Could not load  CoreAudioPlugin(0x145a9410)
Could not load  QM3uPlaylistPlugin(0x145a7ff0)

Could not load  QDDSPlugin(0x145a8ae0)
Could not load  QICNSPlugin(0x145a92c0)
Could not load  QICOPlugin(0x145a8760)
Could not load  QJp2Plugin(0x145a8a50)
Could not load  QMngPlugin(0x145a8e60)
Could not load  QTgaPlugin(0x145a8f30)
Could not load  QTiffPlugin(0x145a8fb0)
Could not load  QWbmpPlugin(0x145a9320)
Could not load  genericSensorPlugin(0x145a8da0)
Could not load  IOSSensorPlugin(0x145a8e30)
Could not load  QtQuick2Plugin(0x146a5b80)
Could not load  QTcpServerConnection(0x145a82e0)
Could not load  QGenericEnginePlugin(0x145a87f0)
Could not load  QSQLiteDriverPlugin(0x145a8970)
Could not load  QIOSIntegrationPlugin(0x14539070)
```

Please help me.

Comment: Did you solve this meanwhile?

Answer (score 0):

As of 5.13, sensor gestures are not supported in Qt for iOS

See the compatibility map: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/compatmap.html

I managed to work around it with this extension, linked to the Qt app in a .mm file:

```
#import "UIKit/UIKit.h"

@implementation UIWindow (WoboqWindow)

extern void sendShakeDetectedToRootObject();
- (void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion
  withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"motionEnded %@", event);

    if (motion == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake )
    {
        NSLog(@"Shake it!");
        sendShakeDetctedToRootObject();
    }
}

- (void)motionBegan:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"motionBegan %@", event);
}

@end
```

With this main main.cpp:

```
void sendShakeDetectedToRootObject() {
    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(rootObject, "shakeDetected");
}
```

The rootObject you get from the QML engine.